# Is it OK to use Metasploit against sites like hackthissite.org?

Tags: metasploit

Is it OK to use exploits like those on Metasploit or similar against legally hackable sites? If not, is there any other servers that are open to that?

Comment: Why would you even want to? I doubt Metasploit would be any help.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the Terms of Service for the hackable sites. They will tell you what they allow.

For Metasploit, they produce Metasploitable, which is a VM to use as target practice.

Comment: Also, would it be OK to create a Wordpress site and mess with that?

Comment: If you spin up your own server with a hosting company, you can do whatever your hosting company allows. I'm confused, though: why not spin up your own VMs on your local machine?